# ElasticSearch range query isn't returning results within the range

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I've really been struggling with getting this to work. Would really appreciate any help with this. Basically I have a time_period field that contain an array of two unix timestamps:

```
time_period: [1660410000000, 1660842000000]
```

I'm doing a a range query with two timestamps:

```
range: {
    time_period: {
        gte: <timestamp>,
        lte: <timestamp>
    }
}
```

basically I want to get any record where the time_period timestamps overlap in any way with the gte and lte timestamps. It works great EXCEPT for when the gte and lte are WITHIN the time_period range. Then I get nothing.

I figured the default "intersects" relation would work like this, but it doesn't. Any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [`date_range` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) which is meant for this type of use.

You should map `time_period` like this:

```
...
"time_period": {
   "type": "date_range"
}
...
```

Then your document would contain this:

```
"time_period": {
    "gte": 1660410000000,
    "lte": 1660842000000
}
```

And your `range` query would work out of the box.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help, it's been a struggle. Hope you have a great day!